# Insert VBA into formula formatting?

Tags: vba, excel

Really quick question on how to format VBA in excel formulas.  When you are inserting a formula into excel and you want to insert a variable from vba for example if b is a string you would use `" & b & "` is that the correct formatting?  To illustrate the problem I have the code below and tried to use that formatting and well... I don't know why it wont work, I get a (Compile error: Expected: End of statement).  Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

```
Dim HrsSTD As String
Dim HrsSAT As String
Dim HrsSUN As String
Dim HrsSTWN As String
Dim sdFormula

HrsSTD = ActiveCell.Address
Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
HrsSAT = ActiveCell.Address
Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
HrsSUN = ActiveCell.Address
Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
HrsSTWN = ActiveCell.Address

sdFormula = "=IF((" & Range(NamedRange).Cells(2, 1).Address & _
       "=""Please add a title"",0,VLOOKUP((" & Range(NamedRange).Cells(2, 1).Address & _
       ",'Tables (H)'!$H$2:$J$6,2,FALSE)* _
" & HrsSTD & "+VLOOKUP(" & Range(NamedRange).Cells(2, 1).Address & _
       ",'Tables (H)'!$H$2:$J$6,2,FALSE)* _
" & HrsSAT & "*1.25+VLOOKUP((" & Range(NamedRange).Cells(2, 1).Address & _
       ",'Tables (H)'!$H$2:$J$6,2,FALSE)*" & HrsSUN & "* _
1.5+VLOOKUP((" & Range(NamedRange).Cells(2, 1).Address & _
       ",'Tables (H)'!$H$2:$J$6,2,FALSE)*" & HrsSTWN & "*0.75)"
```

The code I would type into excel would be:  But I want to change the A13's and the I16 (i.e. all the relative references) into variables in VBA

```
=IF(A13="Please add a title",0,VLOOKUP(A13,'Tables (H)'!$H$2:$J$6,2,FALSE)*F16+VLOOKUP(A13,'Tables (H)'!$H$2:$J$6,2,FALSE)*G16*1.25+VLOOKUP(A13,'Tables (H)'!$H$2:$J$6,2,FALSE)*H16*1.5+VLOOKUP(A13,'Tables (H)'!$H$2:$J$6,2,FALSE)*I16*0.75)
```

Comment: What is he `Asterix` in your formula?

Comment: using it as a times, so i.e. the quantity given by HrsSTD is timesed by the Vlookup value

Comment: Can you post the exact excel formula as you would type in Excel?

Comment: I've just posted it up now as an edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying? Also I see that you haven't taken my advice from the previous answer.

One more tip. Break you code in simple parts. It is easier to understand.

The problem with your code is in the line

```
",'Tables (H)'!$H$2:$J$6,2,FALSE)* _
" & HrsSAT & "*1.25+VLOOKUP((" & Range(NamedRange).Cells(2, 1).Address & _
```

You can't write it like that. The first line doesn't have the ending `"`. You cannot carry it forward to the next line like that.

is this what you are trying?

```
Dim sFormula As String
Dim sAddr As String

sAddr = Range(NamedRange).Cells(2, 1).Address

sFormula = "=IF(" & sAddr & _
           "=""Please add a title"",0,VLOOKUP(" & _
           sAddr & ",'Tables (H)'!$H$2:$J$6,2,FALSE)*F16+VLOOKUP(" & _
           sAddr & ",'Tables (H)'!$H$2:$J$6,2,FALSE)*G16*1.25+VLOOKUP(" & _
           ",'Tables (H)'!$H$2:$J$6,2,FALSE)*H16*1.5+VLOOKUP(" & _
           sAddr & ",'Tables (H)'!$H$2:$J$6,2,FALSE)*I16*0.75)"
```

Comment: Ahh yes, my apologies I forgot about that step.  I'll give it another try but I'm still not sure what you mean about the ending ".  I am 4 days into VBA so my apologies if it is terrible

Comment: You see the line `",'Tables (H)'!$H$2:$J$6,2,FALSE)* _` it doesn't have an ending quote.